# CMS search function with PHP & PDO

Tags: php, full-text-search, pdo

I'd like implement a new search function into the CMS airpapr. Airpapr uses PDO to connect to the DB. Should I write the search function myself from the ground up, or are there some good open source search engines that can be used in a PHP/PDO DB setup? If it's recomendable to write the search function myself, are there some good tutorials out there on how to write a search engine with PHP/PDO? The search function itself just has to search two different table rows.

Comment: it has a search function, blog.airpapr.com [search]

Comment: Yes I know, but ATM it's kind of broken and only dose a DB search for the article titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search is more than a function; it is more complex than simple string comparison + substring occurrence counting.

Taking into consideration matched term highlighting, stemming, synonym matching, the affect of stop words and the need for a search index separate to your content database, search is a broad problem best tackled by an existing search system.

A popular option is [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/):

> Its major features include powerful
>   full-text search, hit highlighting,
>   faceted search, dynamic clustering,
>   database integration, rich document
>   (e.g., Word, PDF) handling, and
>   geospatial search. Solr is highly
>   scalable, providing distributed search
>   and index replication, and it powers
>   the search and navigation features of
>   many of the world's largest internet
>   sites.

There is a [Solr library for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) to get you started, not to mention a whole web full of Solr-related resources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but atm I'm looking search tool that can run on a PHP server. Is there any PHP search tool you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are using PDO to connect to the Database, it is a good idea to use non-vendor specific SQL commands, because on of the main features of PDO is the ability to use different DBMSs without having ton change every SQL command.

To write a simple, non-vendor specific search function for using PDO, you can use the SQL `LIKE` [operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp). An example SQL query would look somthing like this:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE pattern
```

Be sure to separate the different search terms a user entered and run a search for each word you want to search for. Also, if you search multiple columns, be sure to filter duplicated entries.

An other thing to notice with PDO is that the `%` required for the `LIKE` operator should be added in the `$sth->execute()` data, not in the normal SQL string. For more information see this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850659/sql-full-text-search-with-php-and-pdo) question.

Here is an example script how a simple search function could look like, using plain ANSI SQL:

```
$searchterm = trim($searchterm);
    $searchterm = explode(' ', $searchterm);
    $this->sql = "SELECT ID 
        FROM ".$db_prefix."_base
        WHERE article_content_title_".$lang."
        LIKE :string1
        OR
        article_content_text_".$lang."
        LIKE :string2";
    foreach ($searchterm as $value) {
        $this->sth = $dbh_pdo->prepare($this->sql);
        $this->sth->execute(array(':string1' => "%$value%", ':string2' => "%$value%"));
        $this->sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        while ($this->row = $this->sth->fetch()) {      
            $this->id[] = $this->row['ID'];

        }
    }
    $this->id = array_unique($this->id);
    $this->id = array_merge($this->id);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->id); $i++) {
        if ($i == count($this->id) - 1) {
            $this->searchResultID .= "id = ".$this->id[$i];
        }
        else {
            $this->searchResultID .= "id = ".$this->id[$i]." OR ";
        }
    }
```

Please note that this is a very **basic** search function, with no valuation of the search results, among other things (e.g.  matched term highlighting, stemming, synonym matching, etc)