# SQL full text search with PHP and PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm trying to write a simple, full text search with PHP and PDO. I'm not quite sure what the best method is to search a DB via SQL and PDO. I found this [this](http://www.emirplicanic.com/php/php-mysql-search-script) script, but it's old MySQL extension. I wrote this function witch should count the search matches, but the SQL is not working. The incoming search string look like this: `23+more+people`

```
function checkSearchResult ($searchterm) {
    //globals
    global $lang; global $dbh_pdo; global $db_prefix;
    $searchterm = trim($searchterm);
    $searchterm = explode('+', $searchterm);
    foreach ($searchterm as $value) {
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*), MATCH (article_title_".$lang.", article_text_".$lang.") AGINST (':queryString') AS score FROM ".$db_prefix."_base WHERE MATCH (article_title_".$lang.", article_text_".$lang.") AGAINST ('+:queryString')";
        $sth = $dbh_pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sql_data = array('queryString' => $value);
        $sth->execute($sql_data);
        echo $sth->queryString;
        $row = $sth->fetchColumn();
        if ($row < 1) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM article_title_".$lang." LIKE :queryString OR aricle_text_".$lang." LIKE :queryString";
            $sth = $dbh_pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sql_data = array('queryString' => $value);
            $sth->execute($sql_data);
            $row = $sth->fetchColumn(); 
        }
    }
    //$row stays empty - no idea what is wrong
    if ($row > 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you prepare the `$sql_data` array, you need to prefix the parameter name with a colon:

```
array('queryString' => $value);
```

should be:

```
array(':queryString' => $value);
```

In your first `SELECT`, you have `AGINST` instead of `AGAINST`.

Your second `SELECT` appears to be missing a table name after `FROM`, and a `WHERE` clause.  The `LIKE` parameters are also not correctly formatted.  It should be something like:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$db_prefix."_base WHERE article_title_".$lang." LIKE '%:queryString%' OR aricle_text_".$lang." LIKE '%:queryString%'";
```

**Update 1 >>**

For *both* `SELECT` statements, you need unique identifiers for each parameter, and the `LIKE` wildcards should be placed in the value, not the statement.  So your second statement should look like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$db_prefix."_base WHERE article_title_".$lang." LIKE :queryString OR aricle_text_".$lang." LIKE :queryString2";
```

Note `queryString1` and `queryString2`, without quotes or `%` wildcards.  You then need to update your array too:

```
$sql_data = array(':queryString1' => "%$value%", ':queryString2' => "%$value%");
```

See the *Parameters* section of [PDOStatement->execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) for details on using multiple parameters with the same value.  Because of this, I tend to use question marks as placeholders, instead of named parameters.  I find it simpler and neater, but it's a matter of choice.  For example:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$db_prefix."_base WHERE article_title_".$lang." LIKE ? OR aricle_text_".$lang." LIKE ?";

$sql_data = array("%$value%", "%$value%");
```

**<< End of Update 1**

I'm not sure what the second `SELECT` is for, as I would have thought that if the first `SELECT` didn't find the query value, the second wouldn't find it either.  But I've not done much with MySQL full text searches, so I might be missing something.

Anyway, you really need to check the SQL, and any errors, carefully.  You can get error information by printing the results of [`PDOStatement->errorCode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php):

```
$sth->execute($sql_data);
$arr = $sth->errorInfo();
print_r($arr);
```

**Update 2 >>**

Another point worth mentioning: make sure that when you interpolate variables into your SQL statement, that you only use trusted data.  That is, don't allow user supplied data to be used for table or column names.  It's great that you are using prepared statements, but these only protect parameters, not SQL keywords, table names and column names.  So:

```
"SELECT * FROM ".$db_prefix."_base"
```

...is using a variable as part of the table name.  Make very sure that this variable contains trusted data.  If it comes from user input, check it against a whitelist first.

**<< End of Update 1**

You should read the [MySQL Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html), and the [String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html).  You need to learn how to construct basic SQL statements, or else writing even a simple search engine will prove extremely difficult.

There are plenty of PDO examples on the PHP site too.  You could start with the documentation for [PDOStatement->execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), which contains some examples of how to use the function.

If you have access to the [MySQL CLI](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php), or even PHPMyAdmin, you can try out your SQL without all the PHP confusing things.  If you are going to be doing any database development work as part of your PHP application, you will find being able to test SQL independently of PHP a great help.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I changed the SQL accordingly and dropped the MySQL-specific MATCH operation. I changed the SQL to `SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM ".$db_prefix."_base
   WHERE article_content_title_".$lang."
   LIKE '%:queryString%'
   OR
   article_content_text_".$lang."
   LIKE '%:queryString%'` but the `queryString` is not being replaced. Same code as above, but fixed the syntax errors you pointed out. Any idea why?

Comment: @wowpatrick: When you say that the `queryString` is not being replaced, do you mean that when you echo the statement, the parameters (the `:queryString` parts) have not been replaced with your user-supplied string? If so, that's how prepared statements work. The statement and the parameters are sent separately to MySQL. The client (PHP in this case), does not combine the two. Because they are sent separately, MySQL knows which bits are the statement and which bits are the parameters, so it doesn't have to parse it to find out. This is why it is a good defence against SQL injection.

Comment: @wowpatrick: If you want to see the combined statement, you can check the [MySQL General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html). It's disabled by default, so be sure to read the docs first to see how to enable and use it. Also, have you added the line in your PHP code to display any errors that might be occurring?

Comment: Yep, I added the line, no errors at all. The query works fine if i replace the :queryString with the string that should be replaced, no idea why it's not getting replaced.

Comment: I think I know what it is. Have a look at the *Parameters* section of the [PDOStatement->execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) documentation. Each parameter may only be bound once. So you need to change your parameters to something like `queryString1` and `queryString2`, and update your array accordingly. I'll update my answer...

Comment: @wowpatrick let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1927/discussion-between-mike-and-wowpatrick)